# "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" when jQuery source is listed as first JS file in head tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

This console error, `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`, appears when the app initially loads, causing all jQuery dependent functionality to be unavailable.  Here is the HTML of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Properties</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css">@import url(css/styles.css);</style>
        <style type="text/css">@import url(css/print.css) print;</style>
        <!--this JS library is for offline (and online) use-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libraries/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" async=""></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/shared.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/properties.js"></script>
     </head>
```

Note that the jQuery file for this app is stored locally for the purpose of offline development.

Here is the JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// ...do stuff
}
```

Prior to this version of the JS, the JS was `$(document).ready(function() { // ...do stuff }` but this error `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` was appearing with that version.

Other posts that describe similar reference errors recommend to put the jQuery file in the head as the first script.  So why is a reference error present here when the jQuery file is the first JS file listed in the head tags?

Comment: Your browser "Network" developer tab will show you whether the attempted load of jQuery actually worked.

Comment: Look in Developer Tools, specifically the Network tab

Comment: I'm in Firefox.  The Network tab has 2 bullet points: "Perform a request or Reload the page to see detailed information about network activity" and "Click on the Analyze button to start performance analysis".  Shouldn't it display what happened when the browser opened and this page loaded?

Comment: When I refresh the page, the jQuery loads fine.  This issue seems to occur when the browser is first launched and the page, which is a tab that opens when the browser opens, is loaded.

Comment: This could be because of the async tag at your jquery cdn. It could be that shared.js and properties.js are using jquery as dependency. Note that async tag makes possible to load a js while parsing the other html components. So If any other js are using the jquery then it will surely throw an error if the async js is not yet loaded.

Comment: shared.js and properties.js do indeed depend on jQuery.  Should the async tag be removed?

Comment: Yes, remove `async`. That delays loading jQuery, so it's not loaded when the other scripts run.